# ArrayOutOfBoundsException while using DataBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I just created a new android project and implemented DataBinding, but it doesn't run when I try to use it. It gives me the error:

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
```

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: That's the build process failing, not your app code. Try doing `Clean` in your `Build` menu, and maybe `Invalidate Caches / Restart` in the `File` menu. Those are good steps to take if things are acting weird. You might want to check your dependency versions in your ``build.gradle`` files too - if you're using incompatible versions, you can get this error. Search for `DexArchiveMergerException` and you'll see a lot of info about it and different situations where people have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified your layout file to use the binding syntax yet or have you only added the

```
buildFeatures{
   dataBinding true
}
```

in it?

Comment: Yes I have done both of them, I can use dataBinding programatically, thanks:)